# Is there any Vim plugin for Ruby, like pyFlake for Python?

Tags: ruby, vim

Is there any Vim plugin for Ruby, like pyFlake for Python, which can be used to check the syntax and show all the errors in quickfix window?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try the [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugin. It handles syntax checking for many different filetypes ([full list](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/tree/master/syntax_checkers)).

Answer (score 0):

The best place for Ruby VIM plugins is at https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby

I'm not familiar with the pyflake plugin, but if it's not available in the vim-ruby project, it probably doesn't exist.

There is also a rails vim plugin, if you're interested: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567